# Credentials not working for Excel Power Query Import

Tags: excel, import, credentials

I'm trying to import data from a website that requires me to be logged in to see the data table. I assign my login and password to the course using "basic credentials" and it tells me "invalid credentials." Seems like there should be an easy fix, but I can't figure it out.

Any idea how to get the credentials to work?  Or is it an issue with the web site I'm trying to access?

I tried entering my username and password (validated that it's the one I use to log into the site) as Basic Credentials and I get an "invalid credentials" error.  Logging in anonymously doesn't give me access to the data.

Comment: What website is it?

Comment: It's the results of a data query on stathead.com.  Specifically, https://stathead.com/baseball/player-batting-game-finder.cgi?request=1&match=player_game_count_career&year_min=2023&year_max=2023&team_game_min=3&team_game_max=36&player_game_min=1&player_game_max=9999&ccomp%5B1%5D=gt&cval%5B1%5D=1&cstat%5B1%5D=b_h&GS=GS